# Jmeter: how to retrieve values which is in 2nd line using Regx?

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am retriving Firstname from database and i am storing it in object using REGx(jmeter). Since retrieved data in 2nd row(PF Screenshot), when i send that in api request its going in 2nd row as below. Thus API is returning 400. Please suggest possible solution for this ?

**DB Response:**

```
FirstName

RockyBhai
```

**Used Regx**

```
FirstName([^"]+)
```

**my Req:**

```
{
"name":"${name}",
}
```

**jmeter sent api req:**

```
{
"name":"

RockyBhai

",

}
```

**i am expecting:**

```
{
"name":"RockyBhai",
}
```

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qujWe.png)

Comment: Use `FirstName\s*([^"]*[^"\s])`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew.....IT WORKED :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a pattern that will trim the value captured in Group 1 from whitespaces that are captured as `[^"]` matches any char but `"` (including whitespaces).

You may use

```
FirstName\s*([^"]*[^"\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QAqQHg/1).

**Details**

- `FirstName` - a word
- **`\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces** (this trims the whitespace on the left)
- `([^"]*[^"\s])` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `"`
  - **`[^"\s]` - ... up to the last char before the closest `"` that is not whitespace** (this trims the whitespace on the right).

If you plan to match the name only on one line, add `\n` into the `[^"]` negated character class, `FirstName\s*([^"\n]*[^"\s])`.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

- Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `firstName`
- Regular Expression: `(\w+)`
- Template: `$1$`
- Match No: `2`

[image]

You should be able to access the extracted value as `${firstName}` where required:

[image]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)